# Retrieving filtered messages

Tags: twilio

```
var accountSid = 'AC066a9b14a2a701b556491953c1827f84';
var authToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.list(function(err, data) {
    data.messages.forEach(function(message) {
        console.log(message.body);
    });
});
```

Twilio says I can filter the messages by using `From` or `To` parameter but the document lacks the details. I want to retrieve messages that are sent from `123`. How do  I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
client.messages.list({ 
    from: "34234234",   
}, function(err, data) { 
    data.messages.forEach(function(message) { 
     console.log(message.friendlyName); 
    }); 
});
```

I had to go to the API playground.